# Why is my DEM striped after using Mosaic to New Raster?

Tags: dem

I have two DEMs that I need to merge together, so I used Mosaic to New Raster. The resulting DEM is striped...why is that? What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same CRS for both of the raster files? It seems sometimes these problems can occur like that, see: https://community.esri.com/thread/185805-white-stripes-in-cached-raster-catalog Something else I would try is to make sure both rasters are the same type (.tif, .png or grid).

Comment: Yes, they both have the same CRS, raster type, bit depth, and cell size.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Use the identify tool in in one of the empty bands. I'm guessing it has an elevation value, but the software is not rendering the DEM properly.

Answer (score 0):

What were the cell sizes of the original rasters? Did you resample prior to Mosaic to New Raster, and if so what method? You might try the Resample tool to resample one of the rasters to match the cell size of the other, using the Bilinear method (in the Environment settings for that tool), try snapping your resample raster to the other raster to match its extent). Also make sure you are working in a projected coordinate system.